# Generate several variables by a function in R using adiag from magic-package

Tags: r

I have a vector *n* of the length *l* with different values for each data point and a matrix *m1* that is equal for each data point. Now I call a function that generates *l* new matrices *m2i* using *n* and *m1* as input. After that I want to create a block matrix of these returns using the "adiag"-function from the "Magic"-Package.

So far I first created all m2i and then used them as input for the adiag-function. Can you help me speeding up this procedure? I want to build a function using n and m1 as input and giving the block matrix as return without generating all matrices m2i "manually".

Here is an example of my procedure:

```
   1. n = (112,
           214,
           325)
   2. m1= (1,2,3,
           4,5,6,
           7,8,9)
   3. Use n and m1 as input for a function f1 creating m2i for all i in n:
      m21=(7,8,9,
           10,11,12,
           13,14,15)
      m22=...
      m23=...

    4. Then adiag(m21,m22,m23) to create the block matrix
```

Comment: Could you explain what manipulations are being done to "n" and "m1" to create all "m2" matrices?

Comment: Actually my example was not so good because I chose random numbers. The function creates a var./cov.-matrix for each observation using "n[i]" and m1 as input. "n" won't be manipulated, I only need the "i"th element to calculate the "m2i". "m1" is like a constant, which is the same matrix for each observation. Hope this makes it clear?

Comment: As I understand it, perhaps something like this is helpful? (As example, I assume that the function that takes "n" and "m1", just adds each [i] of "n" to the matrix "m1"): `ff = function(n, m1) do.call(adiag, lapply(n, function(x) x + m1))`; `ff(c(112, 214, 325), matrix(1:9, 3))`